# When I pull php docker images I get errors

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I am building a base local development environment using `docker-compose.yml` and I want to include latest php-fpm version, the `docker-compose.tml` file as bellow:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/code"
            - "./docker/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - devproject

    php:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./docker/php
        container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/code"
        networks:
            - devproject

networks:
    devproject:
        driver: bridge
```

`./docker/php/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14

RUN apk update && apk add \
        curl-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        freetype-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        gettext-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip gd mbstring xml curl json gettext tokenizer
```

I keep getting an error when docker try to get `php` image:

```
❯ docker-compose up -d
Building php
[+] Building 2.9s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14                                                    2.8s
 => [auth] library/php:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                           0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:a8409dff6597f2ef5f7ecd3c672671bb2af9a390073efd74f95c54aa41cba22a: not found
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
```

Even if I try to pull the image individually: `docker pull php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14` I get another error:

```
❯ docker pull php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14
8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.14: Pulling from library/php
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

`.env` file:

```
PROJECT_NAME=myproject
DEV_DOMAIN=docker.local
```

I tried many different `php` versions but all give the above errors:

- php:fpm-alpine3.14
- php:alpine3.14
- php:8.1.0alpha1-fpm-alpine3.14
- php:7.4.20-fpm-alpine3.14

Is there an error in my `docker-compose.yml` or `./docker/php/Dockerfile`?

I searched many sites and forums for similar errors and github issues (such as [docker github issue](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/476)) I tried all the suggested solutions but no luck, while there are many images working well without any issue (nginx, mysql, alpine)

I am using WSL2 for Windows 10 Pro and UBUNTU 20.04 distro

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker-compose build --no-cache php-fpm`